# ear deployment on jboss

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

I am trying to create a new development environment I did necessary action to install jboss, and deployed ear on this new dev env, I am seeing issues below, can anyone help, I am using mysql DB,

```
ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] (main) Error installing to Start: name=persistence.unit:unitName=pier-ear.ear/pier-ejb.jar#PIER-PU state=Create
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: PIER-PU] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:677)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:132)
        at org.jboss.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitDeployment.start(PersistenceUnitDeployment.java:301)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:59)
        at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:150)
        at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66)
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction$JoinpointDispatchWrapper.execute(KernelControllerContextAction.java:241)
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ExecutionWrapper.execute(ExecutionWrapper.java:47)
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchExecutionWrapper(KernelControllerContextAction.java:109)
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchJoinPoint(KernelControllerContextAction.java:70)
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.LifecycleAction.installActionInternal(LifecycleAction.java:221)
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54)
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:774)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:540)
        at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:121)
        at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:51)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1210)

Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not init listeners
        at org.hibernate.event.EventListeners.initializeListeners(EventListeners.java:205)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getInitializedEventListeners(Configuration.java:1338)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1327)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:669)
        ... 62 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.SearchException: Unable to initialize: com.piersystem.services.newdocument.domain.Document
        at org.hibernate.search.store.DirectoryProviderFactory.createDirectoryProvider(DirectoryProviderFactory.java:132)
        at org.hibernate.search.store.DirectoryProviderFactory.createDirectoryProviders(DirectoryProviderFactory.java:63)
        at org.hibernate.search.impl.SearchFactoryImpl.initDocumentBuilders(SearchFactoryImpl.java:404)
        at org.hibernate.search.impl.SearchFactoryImpl.<init>(SearchFactoryImpl.java:119)
        at org.hibernate.search.event.ContextHolder.getOrBuildSearchFactory(ContextHolder.java:30)
        at org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener.initialize(FullTextIndexEventListener.java:79)
        at org.hibernate.event.EventListeners$1.processListener(EventListeners.java:198)
        at org.hibernate.event.EventListeners.processListeners(EventListeners.java:181)
        at org.hibernate.event.EventListeners.initializeListeners(EventListeners.java:194)
        ... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current marker in source directory
        at org.hibernate.search.store.FSSlaveDirectoryProvider.initialize(FSSlaveDirectoryProvider.java:59)
        at org.hibernate.search.store.DirectoryProviderFactory.createDirectoryProvider(DirectoryProviderFactory.java:129)
        ... 74 more
```

Comment: when you get this error during deployment?

Comment: Set `hibernate.search.default.retry_marker_lookup 2` and try. Is you Master is already running? If don't want to set above property then make sure master is already running.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the EAR cannot find the class `com.piersystem.services.newdocument.domain.Document` . Maybe this was an external/proprietary jar ? it is not something that usually comes with hibernate, but hibernate complains because it cannot reference it.

Search for the class in the stack trace.

Comment: first thing I checked that, there is a class Document  in ejb/../newdocument/domain/Document.class and ejb/../newdocument/domain/Document$1.class